# Excessive use of RAM by Oracle HTTP Server

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, memory-usage

I have a problem related to an Oracle HTTP Server (based on Apache) that continues to consume memory up to using all the available RAM.

Do you have any advice on how to identify the problem? I'm in the Linux Red Hat environment. I know it is a question that ranges from a thousand different causes, but I don't know where to look in order to understand the problem.

Is there a way to check how memory has increased, since when and what processes were consuming it? If you need more information to analyze the problem, please tell me so that I can add it to this post.

the output from top command:

```
Tasks: 4 total, 1 running, 3 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie

%Cpu(s): 0.5 us, 0.7 sy, 0.0 ni, 98.8 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st

KiB Mem: 1863252 total, 1016708 free, 269428 used, 575284 buff/cache

Kib Swap: 2097148 total, 2097148 free,    0 used. 1368993 avail Mem

PID     user        PR      NI      VIRT    RES     SHR     S   %CPU    %MEM    TIME        COMMAND
xxx1    oracle      20       0    114300    2896    1748    S   0.0     0.2     0:00.00     bash
xxx2    oracle      20       0     72852    9324    6600    S   0.0     0.5     0:00.00     opmn
xxx3    oracle      20       0   1092736    19760   10040   S   0.0     1.1     0:01.06     opmn
xxx4    oracle      20       0    159996    2088    1524    R   0.0     0.1     0:01.88     top
```

The free ram continues slowly to decrease and increase the used and buff / cache. The used then arrives at a level where it does not grow further, while the buff / cache instead is. When the free memory reaches a level that is too low, the swap memory is used and from here you start having problems related to performance. The buff / cache memory always remains high.

Comment: Start with the `top` command...

Comment: I forgot to add what you rightly told me. With top user oracle I see 4 processes: top (obviously), 2 opmn, 1 bash.
The free ram continues slowly to decrease and increase the used and buff / cache. The used then arrives at a level where it does not grow further, while the buff / cache instead is.
When the free memory reaches a level that is too low, the swap memory is used and from here you start having problems related to performance. The buff / cache memory always remains high.

Comment: Please add that (best as text copy/paste) to your question

Comment: Hi, does anyone have any suggestions for me?